script does not work
I can successfully execute this command from the terminal:
sudo cp -R -u "/media/gabriela/Windows/Data/Untitled Folder" /media/gabriela/USB
But the following script does not work, with the appropriate entries entered:
sudo bash /home/gabriela/Desktop/copyfolder.sh

(to start the script, not part of the script)
read source

read destination

cp -R -u source destination

The error message says, cp: cannot stat 'source': No such file or directory.
This is with the exact same info entered as in the plain cp command which works.

To get the values of the variables you need "$source" and "$destination" rather than source and destination - but it is usually preferable to pass arguments to the script (see for example Passing arguments to a script) rather than read them interactively

Thank you, the first suggestion worked with modification (see below).  I am not (yet) smart enough to figure out the suggestion about passing arguments to a script.  Thanks again.

If you want to read the values at runtime you should use the following syntax:
read source
read destination
cp -R -u "$source" "$destination"

It's essential to use the dollar sign and the double quotes when you want to use the variables afterwards.

Thank you.  I fixed that syntax but got the same error.  Then I tried renaming the source folder to simply Untitled (removing the space so no quote marks were needed) and then it worked.  And now I tried it one more time with the original folder name but without quote marks, and that worked too.  So I guess spaces are OK without quotation marks when the script is set like this.  Thank you for your help, it works now.

@GabrielaRemow no, spaces are never OK without quotes. Always quote your variables. Also, if one of the answers here solved your issue, please take a moment and accept it by clicking on the checkmark on the left. That is the best way to express your thanks on the Stack Exchange sites.
